# Why Angular ngFor does not check if the iterable object existing?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template, ngfor

I am complete new to Angular 2. My understanding of Angular 2 is that it is based on TypeScript which compiles the source code to Javascript. As a compile language, I would expect it is able to catch any undefined variable, but it seems that it is not the case for `ngFor`. For example,  in the following code (I am using VS Code), `ngFor` is used for iterate object `heroes`, it does not give me any error if `heroes` is not defined (when I defined `heroes`, I got a typo and defined it as `heros`, last second line):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
*export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',  
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>My Heroes</h2>
    <ul class="heroes">
      <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" >
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
`
})
export class AppComponent  { 
  name = 'Angular'; 
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heros = HEROES;
}*
```

Could somebody kindly explain to me why? Do I expect too much?

Comment: where is the code you're working?

Comment: Take a few minutes to read and understand [ask] and [mcve] then update the question with proper details and relevant code

Comment: The question is complete enough. it was just the formatting that was messed up so the code wasn't visible.

Comment: I for example would expect an error message "it seems that it does not check if `heroes` has been defined" is not helpful. It's entirely unclear what the question is about. Why do you expect Angular checks for undefined variables and why do you think it does not?

Answer (score 1):

If the property referenced by `*ngFor` to iterate over is `null` or `undefined`, `*ngFor` just doesn't do anything. You won't get an error for this.
TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript and undefined is a perfectly valid value for a property in JS and TS.

Angular2 for Dart however produces an error for such cases.

Comment: I think a warning in this case would be handy.

Comment: From a TS point if view there is norhing to warn about (as mentioned). There are Angular language services for template auto-completion and additional linter checks work in progress (or even already available - I'm not up to date abour the status) that might provide such a check.